# How to fix 'This expression is not constructable ' error in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am begginer with ts and react,an  I get error while creating a new class object of auth service.

```
const Auth = new Authentication();
```

***Error***

> This expression is not constructable.   Type 'typeof
> import("c:/react-js/portfolio/src/Services/IdentityServices/Authentication")'
> has no construct signatures.

**my Authentication Service**

```
import axios from 'axios';

class AuthenticationServices {
  API_URL = 'https://localhost:44382/api/authenticate/';

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    return axios
      .post(this.API_URL + 'login', {
        username,
        password,
      })
      .then((reponse) => {
        if (reponse.data.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(reponse.data));
        }

        return reponse.data;
      });
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
  }

  register(username: string, password: string, email: string) {
    return axios.post(this.API_URL + 'register', {
      username,
      password,
      email,
    });
  }

  getCurrenUser() {
    let currentUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if (currentUser) return JSON.parse(currentUser);

    return 'Current user is empty';
  }
}
```

**My register component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Form, Button, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { RegisterPage } from '../Pages/RegisterPage';
import * as Authentication from '../Services/IdentityServices/Authentication';

type IFormInput = {
  email: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
};

export const Register = () => {
  const {
    register,
    watch,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<IFormInput>();

  const [createUser, setCreateUser] = React.useState<IFormInput>();
  const Auth = new Authentication();
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

      return (
        <Container>
          <Row></Row>
          <RegisterPage title="Kayıt Ol">
            <Container>
              <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center   ">
                <Col xs={5} className="shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded ">
                  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                      <Form.Label>Email adresi</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Enter email"
                        {...register('email')}
                      />
                      <Form.Text className="text-muted"></Form.Text>
                    </Form.Group>
    
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                      <Form.Label>Kullanıcı Adı</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Kullanı adı"
                        {...register('username')}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
    
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                      <Form.Label>Şifre</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Şifre"
                        {...register('password')}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                      Kayıt ol
                    </Button>
                  </Form>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Container>
          </RegisterPage>
        </Container>
      );
    };
```

Comment: The import/export is wrong. Look at how you are importing the class in your component and exporting from Auth class.

Comment: How is the auth class exported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import * as Authentication` imports the module's *module namespace object*, which has properties for each of the module's exports; it's not constructible.

You haven't shown any export of `AuthenticationServices`, so it's hard to tell you how to import it. **If** you exported it as a named export (generally preferred), like this:

```
export AuthenticationServices;
```

...then you'd import it with `{}`, like this:

```
import { AuthenticationServices } from "...";
// or if you want to rename it
import { AuthenticationServices as Authentication } from "...";
```

If you export it as the default export, like this:

```
export default AuthenticationServices;
```

...then you'd import it like this:

```
import AuthenticationServices from "...";
// Or if you want to use a different name
import Authentication from "...";
```

Comment: How can I use a wildcard import and still have ts see it as constructable?

Comment: @Stefan_EOX - The `*` import imports the *module namespace object*, which is not constructible. But if you exported something from that module that *is* constructible, it will be available as a property on the module namespace object. For instance, if you have `export class A { }` and `export default class B { }` in `mod.js`, then in another module you have `import * as t from "./mod.js";`, you can do `new t.A()` to create an `A` instance and `new t.default()` to create a `B` instance (`B` is called `default` on the namespace object because it's the default export).

Comment: @Stefan_EOX - Side note: Although I included a default export in my example there, I recommend avoiding them. I **only** use default exports when I have to work with a library/framework that requires me to use them (such as the [Fresh framework](https://fresh.deno.dev) for Deno, which requires them for route files). Otherwise, I stick with named exports. It adds consistency and clarity to a codebase (IMHO).

Comment: Thank you! I found out that I have a slightly different error message: `Each member of the union type '...' has construct signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.` So the namespacing works, but I cannot simply do `new t [<className>]` because not all constructors are compatible.

Comment: @Stefan_EOX - Sounds like you're exporting a union of constructors (in TypeScript). How you solve that will be highly specific to what you're doing.